# find running services in android

Tags: android

This is my method for searching services

```
public static boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceClassName, Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (activityManager == null) {
            return false;
        }

        List<RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        if (services.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : services) {
            if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceClassName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

but sometimes i get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.xx.xx.receiver.BluetoothReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xx.xx.receiver.BluetoothReceiver
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2111)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xx.x.receiver.BluetoothReceiver
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-06 17:39:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(7259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2106)
```

is it smart to use this method. I want to find if service is running or not. And if not i run it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but sometimes i get this error:

That error would appear to have nothing to do with the code you have shown.

> I want to find if service is running or not. And if not i run it manually.

Just start the service. If it is already running, nothing will happen, except that it will be called with `onStartCommand()` again. If it is not already running, an instance of the service will be created, called with `onCreate()`, and then called with `onStartCommand()`.